# The BJT configuration representing a single pole double throw switch

Tags: switches, spdt

How is the simplest BJT configuration for performing a single pole double throw switch?

Comment: Depends on what you want to use it for. [Edit] your question to share more details.

Comment: It's fairly simple with DC switching (although MOSFETs are better) and a lot more complex when emulating a switch that controls AC at high currents and voltages and, is expected to be isolated from ground/earth. It gets harder as the bandwidth of the voltages/currents increase also. Hence, there is no general answer to your question; there is no "one size fits all" solution by a long way.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the circuit below.

[image]

For more details please see this [link](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/simple-bjt-based-spdt.140924/).